# Standalone/Embedded Web Server to make a portable Web app

Tags: java

I come across the following options to make a portable web application in java

1. Spring Boot with embedded tomcat - Not sure how to build for windows, linux and mac
2. Jetty embedded server - http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html
3. Tiny - https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd
4. JLHttp - https://www.freeutils.net/source/jlhttp/#whatsnew
5. Undertow - https://www.stubbornjava.com/guides/embedded-java-web-server and http://undertow.io/blog/index.html

Not sure which one is the best to go..Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first choice(Spring Boot with embedded tomcat) is easy according to my experience. I have used the Spring boot embedded tomcat for the deployment of both Linux and Windows. I will explain how to deploy using embedded tomcat. Still then, the decision is yours to choose.

**Ubuntu**

*1. Create executable jar/war file:* You can create an executable war/jar by adding the following configuration in your pom.xml file or you can change the permission of the jar/war file using the Linux commands.

Add the following configuration in your plugin session of the pom.xml file as follows:-

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Then open the terminal and navigate inside the project folder and run the following command:-

```
mvn clean install
```

As soon as you run the above command, you will get an executable war/jar(as you mentioned in the pom.xml) /target folder inside the project.

(or)

You can skip adding the above configuration and use Linux commands to make the war/jar as executable one. To do so, just open the terminal and navigate to the project folder. Then run the following command:

```
mvn clean install
```

You will get the war/jar in the /target folder which is not executable. You can make it executable using the following Linux commands:-

```
chmod 777 file_name
```

2. As soon as you get the executable jar/war, then you are ready to deploy it as a Linux service now. Because when you run it as a service, you don't need to restart it time after time whenever the server gets restarted. By default, the spring boot jar/war file has the ability to support **init.d** service commands like(status, start, stop, restart). To run it as a Linux init.d service, use the following steps:-

   Copy your jar/war file to the **/var** folder(No problem even if you keep the jar/war in some other locations) using the following command.

   **cp file_absolute_path destination_path**

   *e.g cp /opt/test/test.jar /var/test/*

   then create a **symbolic link** to the jar or war file as follows in **/etc/init.d** folder using the following command.

   **ln -s file_path symbolic_link_path**

   *e.g ln -s /var/test/test.jar /etc/init.d/test*

   So the service has been created now. You could check the status of the service using the following command:-

   **sudo service service_name status**

   *e.g sudo service test status*

   if you get an error like **Unit test.service not found**, then execute the following command to enable the service.

   **sudo systemctl enable service_name**

   *e.g sudo systemctl enable test*

   and then execute the status command, you will get the status of the service.

   In a similar way, you can use other commands also to start, stop and restart the service.

   **sudo service service_name start/stop/restart**

**Windows**

Even though there are more ways, I would like to explain about running the tomcat as a service which is quite simple. Use to following steps to do so:-

1. Disable the embedded tomcat inside the spring boot application by adding the following command in *application.properties*

   **spring.main.web-environment=false**

(or) add the following configuration in your spring boot application main class:-

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class, 
                                  WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
```

2. Then build the war file using the Maven command mentioned above:

   **mvn clean install**
3. Copy the war file from the /target folder.
4. Download a tomcat 7 or above version for windows from the official site [tomcat.org](https://tomcat.apache.org/)
5. Copy your war file and paste it to the tomcat/webapp folder.
6. Open Command prompt and navigate to the tomcat's /bin folder
7. Execute the **service.bat** as follows to create a service.

   **service.bat install service_name**
8. Open Services manager and you could see a service running with the service_name as you created.
9. when you select the service, you could see the options like start/stop/restart on the left side.

[image: Services Tab]

10. You can also make the service to run automatically whenever the system gets restarted. **Select service -> Right Click -> Properties -> Startup Type -> Select Automatic**

[image: Properties]

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about java, Spring is the hottest and most demanding framework of all. Undoubtedly go for option 1. Few reasons to use Spring are as below

1. Less coding, more productivity
2. Integration with database simpler using Spring JPA
3. Template made easy by Spring Thymeleaf
4. Rest calls made concise with Spring Rest Template
5. Form validation modularized by Spring Validator.
6. Secure application using Spring Security
7. Define workflows using Spring State Machine
8. Numerous articles and example available over internet
9. Community and developer support easily available

.. and many more