# How to run war file as a service on Windows 7?

Tags: war

How can I run the war file as a service on Windows? Actually, I want to run my war file when I start my machine. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is a spring boot application then you just refer this link:-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58637513/8199738

If your application is not made up of spring boot then just follow the below steps:-

1. Download a tomcat 7 or above version for windows from the official site [tomcat.org](https://tomcat.apache.org/)
2. Copy your war file and paste it to the tomcat/webapp folder.
3. Open Command prompt and navigate to the tomcat's /bin folder
4. Execute the service.bat as follows to create a service.

   **service.bat install service_name**
5. Open Services manager and you could see a service running with the service_name as you created.
6. when you select the service, you could see the options like start/stop/restart on the left side.
   [image]
7. You can also make the service to run automatically whenever the system gets restarted. **Select service -> Right Click -> Properties -> Startup Type -> Select Automatic.**
   [image]

Hope! it helps! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the code that you use to start your .war file to a batch file then add that batch file to Windows startup folder.